# SSAS dimension member grouping

Tags: ssas, olap, olap-cube

I am new to SSAS and i have a problem with the dimension members for which i haven't been able to find a solution. Is it possible to group dimension members  like:

Member 1
Member 2_1
Member 2_2
Member 2_3
Member 3
...

so that the user browsing the cube will see only Member 1, Member 2, Member 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group the dimension members on the way into the cube (within your etl or views), but you will have to group the related fact records for it to make sense.  If the dimension should be treated as the collected set and not subdivided this would be preferable.

Alternatively, if the sub dimension values make sense on their own and should be persisted alongside, you could create a hierarchy of members within SSAS relating the sub values to your desired parent value.